# Android ignoring my notification sound when a specific icon is chosen

Tags: android, notifications, alert

When the iconIndex of my notification = 0, it looks for the name in the array on position 0, and returns "ic_alert", which is the name of the icon. But only when this icon is chosen, it doesn't want to play the notification sound, even though isPlaySound() returns true, so weird... Other icons work fine

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Log.e("ALARMRECEIVER","ONRECEIVE");

    //Create a notification
    long notificationId = intent.getLongExtra("id", -1);

    if(notificationId == -1)
    {
        Log.e("AlarmReceiver","id went missing");
    }
    else
    {
        NotificationRepository repository = NotificationRepository.getInstance(context);
        Notification notification = repository.getNotification(notificationId);


        if(notification != null)
        {

            String[] icons = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.icons);
            int iconId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(context.getPackageName()
                    + ":drawable/" + icons[notification.getIconIndex()], null, null);


            String icon =  icons[notification.getIconIndex()];

            //create the android notification
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(iconId)
                    .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                    .setContentText(notification.getSubtitle())
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));

            if(notification.isPlaySound())
            {
                mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
                Log.e("ALARMRECEIVER", "SOUND");
            }
            else Log.e("ALARMRECEIVER","NO SOUND");

            if (notification.isVibrate())
            {
                mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000});
            }

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
            mNotificationManager.notify((int) notificationId, mBuilder.build());
            //Delete the notification from the database
            repository.removeNotification(notificationId);

            Intent i = new Intent("dvanack.gmail.com.NOTIFY");
            context.sendBroadcast(i);
            Log.w("ONRECEIVE","ENDED");
        }
```

Comment: I think it might be a bug in Android

Comment: I have solved it, It was Cyanogen because all other phones worked fine and it was solved by an update

Comment: @XaverKapeller Actually, 99% of the time when one runs Cyanogenmod, one rightfully blames Android, but must never forget to specify that it is a particular interpretation of Android. Had it been originally stated this was being built against Cyanogenmod, no one would have questioned that assertion.

Comment: Yeah sorry i was totally wrong thinking it was Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have this problem with other devices than the One Plus one running Cyanogenmod, this was fixed the day after with an update ...